# c++ boost async_read performance

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

its my first time to use boost/asio library..
and some performance problem here.. plz help me..
sorry for my poor english

i have a tcp socket client. and the code like these.

i initialize io_service, tcp::socket, io_service::strand with the same io_service.

```
class(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) 
 :io_service_(io_service), socket_(io_service), strand_(io_service) {}
```

and here is the code to set async_read.

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer_.data(), buffer_.header_size()), 
        strand_.wrap( boost::bind( &handle_recv_header, 
        shared_from_this(), 
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred) ));
```

and in "handle_recv_header" func

```
if ( !error && buffer_.decode_header() ){
    if ( !error && buffer_.decode_header() ){
        boost::asio::async_read(
        socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer_.data(), buffer_.body_size()),
        strand_.wrap(
        boost::bind(&handle_recv_body,
        shared_from_this(),
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred) ) );
    }}
```

the problem is when i test to dispatch a packet size of (4 ~ 1000 bytes)

it costs nearly 0 ms to call the handle_recv_header
and costs 0.2(!!!!) sec to call the handle_recv_body

i just cannot understand why it takes so much time to dispatch a packet?
any problems with my code?
or any better way to make a tcp-socket client?

and i find other questions in stack overflow. 
and one of the solution is 
`myPort->set_option(tcp::no_delay(true))` and did not work.

thx.

Comment: There's no obvious error in this code. What do you mean with 0.2s to call handle_recv_body? Does it take 0.2s from the decode_header part until handle_recv_body is called? Or does the execution of the function body of handle_recv_body take so long? In the latter case we can't help, since we don't see it and it's probably your business logic.

Comment: The only strange thing is that the `if (!error ...)` is repeated two times in the last code block. But I guess that's a copy&paste error into the form here.

Comment: thx Matthias247. there is an error to add a comment in mobile.. in the second comment you are right. and the first one, i think it might be the first case. it took too much time to receive a packet body. to check if it was to network problem, i tested similar way by using http and it was much faster.. 2~4(ms). i wonder what is the problem? why is tcp slower than http..

Comment: TCP is for sure not slower than HTTP since HTTP is based on TCP. The only possible explaination that I have is that the server is strangely implemented and takes too long for sending. You could check that with wireshark.

Comment: thx Matthias247 very much. i'll try to test with wireshark.